# browser debugger - how to change script code

Tags: html, jquery, browser

I have simple script that show alert message when you click on link.

How can I use browser (chrome or firefox) debugger in order to change the alert content?

I know how to change he HTML, but not script code...

Thanks

Send

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> 
<script>

    $(document).on("click", "#show_alert", function(e){

        alert ("Alert to change here");
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Do you only want to change the alert message i.e  from "Alert to change here" to "New Alert Message" ?

Comment: @MubsherMughal - yes. i wan to know how to change script code with the browser debug tool